# My VS Code SCM gutter indicator has a bizarre pattern on it suddenly

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gutter

My gutter indicators in VS Code (seemingly randomly) switched from a solid color (blue) to patterned (blue with repeating black diagonal lines), a la:

[image: screenshot]

I've not found anything here or in my settings that can undo or affect this. Does anyone know how to revert back to a solid color, and/or why this happened and what it means?

Comment: VSCode has its own support system via Github Issues. This has already been reported there ~ https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146220

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Release Notes: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_updated-source-control-decorators

> In order to make the source control decorators more visible for
> accessibility, we've added a new pattern for modified lines and
> increased the contrast for all decorators.

I don't think you can go back to a solid color yet (until the v1.67 release - see below thanks to @Phil), you can only change the colors of the "stripes" with the `colorCustomization`: `"editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#ff0000",` [or go back to v1.65 until the issue gets sorted]

---

As @Phil reports, there is already an option in the Insiders Build:

`SCM: Diff Decorations Gutter Pattern`

[image: diff decorations gutter pattern setting]

Unselect the `Use pattern for the diff decorations in gutter for modified lines. (modified)`  The default is enabled.

Comment: [Already fixed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146220#issuecomment-1090104107) in the 2022-04-06 Insider Release